# Stripe order of events

Tags: stripe-payments

if in the invoice.payment_succeeded event I put:

```
echo "HELLO";
$previous_subscription_obj->cancel();
echo "WORLD";
```

and in the customer.subscription.deleted event I put:

```
echo "JANE";
```

Will the code of the delete event be executed before the end of the invoice succeeded event ? in other words , will I have HELLO WORLD JANE ? OR HELLO JANE WORLD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends. Order of Events is not guaranteed.

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#event-ordering